# Not printing logs in console of Logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've removed all system.out.println() in my code, and added Logger of apache log4j. But nothing is getting printed in my console. Here is my log4j.properties file

```
# Define the root logger with appender X
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, X

# Set the appender named X to be a File appender
log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Define the layout for X appender
log4j.appender.X.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.X.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

I'm calling logger class as follows

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PersonImpl.class.getName());
```

In addition to my log.info(), other logs are getting printed.

```
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (Table.java:505) - No alter strings for table : hibernate_sequence
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (JtaPlatformInitiator.java:42) - No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (JtaPlatformResolverInitiator.java:33) - No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (StandardJtaPlatformResolver.java:101) - Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (NamedQueryRepository.java:149) - Checking 0 named HQL queries
DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] (NamedQueryRepository.java:165) - Checking 0 named SQL queries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have only added a `FileAppender` (this will cause logs to be written only in file) but you will also need to add a `ConsoleAppender` if you want logging to be done in console as well.

it can be done as follows:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and also add the name of appender in rootLogger,like this

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, X, stdout
```

apart from this if you want to shutdown Hibernate specific logs, you will have to do

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=fatal or log4j.logger.org.hibernate=off
```

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: thanks.. But, in addition to log info, its printing lottttt of lines of other lines too. I don't want all other lines

Comment: I mean to say I don't want other logs, except the logs which I write in my code.

Comment: can you help us with example by putting up lines that you don't want, we cant help without exactly knowing the problem

Comment: Ok.. I'm upating the question again.

Comment: Updated. Please check

Comment: ok, try adding this line to log4j file `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info`

Comment: Even now also, its same. 2016-02-26 11:37:57 DEBUG logging:28 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
2016-02-26 11:37:57 INFO  Version:37 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
2016-02-26 11:37:57 INFO  Environment:213 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-02-26 11:37:57 INFO  Environment:317 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-02-26 11:37:58 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}

Comment: My logs are getting printed in addition to other logs :(

Comment: ok turn it off by doing this `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=fatal` or `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=off` whichever works

Comment: I see that the other logs prints only for the first time when I start the tomcat server. Anyways there are other logs too which are not part of hibernate.

Comment: that will happen because they might be server specific logs which you cant turn off

Comment: Cool then. Put your answer in an updated one. Will mark as correct.

Comment: added that to answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to the class at where u want to generate the logs actually.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Class Name Where u used");
LOGGER.error ("string which u want to print");
LOGGER.info("string which u want to print");
LOGGER.warn("string which u want to print");
```

> Use this setting I have do it in my project. It will generate your logs to console as well as logger.out to your project directory

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logger.out
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=100

# Define the layout for file appender
   log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

> Happy To Help !

Comment: Its not getting printed. Only hibernate query is getting printed but not log.info()

Comment: No :(.. Same thing.. Only hibernate query

Comment: What is prm_sMessage? I've already written Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PersonImpl.class.getName());

Comment: why negative for this @Syed ?? i may be a setting problem in your project setting and you are putting a down vote for me? just a wow Thank You for such a warm appriciation..

Comment: No. It was done by mistake. May be it was clicked by mistake. I've up voted.

Comment: please see my updated question again. other lines are also getting printed in my console, which I dont want

Comment: Thanks for your help Vikrant.

Answer (score 0):

U can print the logs in file

log4php.appender.services = LoggerAppenderDailyFile

log4php.appender.services.layout = LoggerLayoutPattern

log4php.appender.services.datePattern = Y-m-d

log4php.appender.services.file = /home/Logs_%s

log4php.appender.services.layout.ConversionPattern = "%24d{ISO8601} [%p] %F:%L %m %n"

log4php.rootLogger = debug, services

Comment: Vishal I don't want in any file. I just want in my console and that too only my logs.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout